# redirect rule for http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

Checking web master tools I've found a third party has incorrectly linked to my site with a url following this pattern:

http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com

I added in a rule to my htaccess file, however I get a 403 forbidden response.

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com / [r=301,l,nc]
```

How should I go about resolving this rule?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you try to fix this on your end?

Comment: @Sven I've emailed the third party but had no response. I should make efforts on my end to ensure traffic is routed correctly